# Why is relative URL faster in PHP file_get_contents?

Tags: php, url, path, file-get-contents

I use PHP and [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/function.file-get-contents). It was really slow even when I tried to speed it up with this:

```
$opts = array(
    'http'=> array(
    'header' => 'Connection: close'
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$contents = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/file.txt', false, $context);
```

I also tried `cURL`. Same issue.

I've read that `include` should be slower than `file_get_contents`. That seems only to be true when NOT including the whole URL but including the relative path, like this...

```
file_get_contents('../file.txt');
```

My question is... Why is the relative path much faster than the full URL?

Comment: Perhaps second one uses local file system, instead of http?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file_get_contents` doesn't accept a relative URI. It takes either an absolute URI or a file path.

Using a file path is faster because:

- Reading from the file system

is less work than:

- Making an HTTP request
- Reading the request
- Loading a file from the file system (possibly executing PHP on the way)
- Putting it in an HTTP response
- Sending the response
- Reading the response
- Getting the file data out of the response body